# Trying to build simple tag system with php

Tags: php, pdo

In my database I have a table called topics, in the table there is the tags column where the tags are stored in a comma-separated order (for example `$row['tags'] = "tag1,tag2,tag3,...".` What I'm trying to do is display related topics depending on the tags that each has. The code below identifies only the single "tag" it finds (for example `$row['tags'] ="tag1"`). Do you have something to suggest? Thanks in advance.

```
 <?php
    $result_topic = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topics.topic_id = :id");
    $result_topic->bindValue(':id',$topic_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_topic -> execute();
    while($row = $result_topic->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
$tag = explode(",",$row['tags']);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($tag); $i++){
            $current_tag = $tag[$i];
           $relative_topics = $conn -> prepare("SELECT topic_subject FROM topics WHERE tags LIKE ?");
           $relative_topics -> bindParam(1,$current_tag);
            $relative_topics -> execute();
            $get_relative_topics = $relative_topics -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo $get_relative_topics['topic_subject'].'<br>';
                                }

       }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) :

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the
>   pattern:
>   % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>   _ matches exactly one character.

so, you need to use the `%` wildcard in your query:

```
$current_tag = "%" . $tag[$i] . "%";
$relative_topics = $conn -> prepare("SELECT topic_subject FROM topics WHERE tags LIKE ?");
```

Comment: Now it matches topics with only the same tag order.

Comment: so, you are talking about [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) feature, which is must be initialized when you are creating your table, and needs a specific engine and mysql version, it is not about your OP now :-)

Comment: however , it will be great chance to learn more about [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) :)

Comment: this will avoid you such a problems

Answer (score 0):

You could try using following SQL query -

```
$relative_topics = $conn -> prepare("SELECT topic_subject FROM topics WHERE tags LIKE %?%");
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%'Java'%' at line 1' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Brainstorming\topic.php:351 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\Brainstorming\topic.php(351): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Brainstorming\topic.php on line 351